# Perfect prediction results with risk of overfitting?

Tags: python, testing, classification, binary-search, training-data

I am performing a binary classification task using MLPClassifier and I followed the following structure: Removing null rows and columns, imputation, removal of outliers, balancing the dataset and training. I performed the train_test_split of the dataset after imputation,and when using normal split the results are pretty normal, but using a kennard-stone split the predictions on the test set suddenly jump to 100% (see the image below). I performed cross-validation of the training data (cv=5, scoring F1-macro) to test for overfitting and the results are 97% accuracy. Should I use any other method to test for overfitting? Am I doing something horribly which overfits the dataset? Its a relatively small testing sample (270 samples vs. 981 for training) hence might overfit by tuning parameters. Any help on how to test this to deliver reliable results is appreciated :)

[image]